# Привязка команды к ресурсу

Tags: c#, wpf

В разметке есть несколько не однотипных элементов, которые используют одну и ту же команду.

Пример:

```
<Border>
    <Border.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick" 
                      Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, 
                                Path=DataContext.Popup.HideCommand}"/>
    </Border.InputBindings>
</Border>

...

<Button Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}},
                  Path=DataContext.Popup.HideCommand}" />
```

Возможно ли вынести привязку команды в ресурсы и привязываться уже к одному объекту?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660760/defining-inputbindings-within-a-style

Comment: А в чем смысл? Вы хотите сократить текст разметки привязки? Вместо запихивания этого в ресурсы (я не смог придумать рабочего способа это сделать), можно написать свое простое расширение разметки, как здесь: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40761541#40761541 Код сократится до таких же размеров, как если бы вы использовали бы ресурсы

Comment: @АндрейNOP, Да, хотелось бы, чтобы разметка выглядела менее громоздко. Расширение разметки это хорошо, но тогда упираемся в то, что придется задавать путь от фиксировано заданного родителя.

Comment: Ну напишите 2 расширения разметки или 3. Код C# легко выносится в отдельные мелкие файлы, в отличие от XAML-разметки, которая гораздо труднее может быть упрощена